# What is the state-of-the-art on spacelike singularities in string theory?

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, research-level, singularities

What lessons do we have from string theory regarding the fate of singularities in general relativity?

What happens to black hole singularities? What happens to cosmological singularities?

Which points of view on string theory yielded results in this respect? String field theory? AdS/CFT? Matrix theory? I suppose perturbative string theory is not applicable in the vicinity of singularities.

Comment: Is there a way to narrow this down? The story of timelike singularities (orbifolds, conifolds etc.) is well digested and you are asking for a review of thousands of papers. Are you maybe interested in more specific types of singularities?

Comment: Well, I mentioned black hole and cosmological singularities which are spacelike. Indeed I'm interested only in the spacelike case.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, this does narrow it down quite a bit...

Comment: Also, my 1st sentence alludes to the classical problem of singularities in general relativity which a theory of quantum gravity is supposed to solve. Compactification on singular manifolds (which I think you're referring to) is a way to introduce an additional sort of singularities special to string theory (more generally Kaluza-Klein) and unnecessary in classical general relativity.

Comment: That’s kind of semantics, but spacelike singularities is definitely a well-defined characterization.

Comment: Dear @Squark, you may get links to dozens of brave papers but I think that except for the authors, mostly everyone will agree that nothing solid has been derived from string theory about spacelike singularities at all so if you get some "constructive answer", it could already mislead you in a direction that was predetermined by how you formulated your question...

Comment: Does it mean we can't answer even the most basic questions? For example: AdS/CFT is supposed to describe quantum gravity on asymptotically anti-De Sitter spacetime. Apparently it includes spacetimes of different topology. Does it include spacetimes with an initial cosmological singularity and asymptotically anti-De Sitter future?

Comment: Only the Schwarzschild singularity is spacelike.  Kerr and Nordstrom singularities are timelike.  Thus, you would expect physical singularities to be timelike, since to get a schwarzschild hole, you have to fine tune the angular momentum of the collapsing matter to exactly zero.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, these spacetimes have Cauchy horizons which see the entire history of the outer universe in a finite time, so the slightest perturbation would be infinitely blueshifted and form a null singularity at worst. This, along with the collapse process to form the black hole, will prevent formation of the timelike singularities (even if you ignore the question of how to continue a Cauchy development into the causal future of such a thing).

Comment: I don't think this is quite an answer, but this seems like a good excuse to post one of my favorite articles: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408106

Comment: @Holographer: that's not what almost any of the models containing matter that I've seen in the absence of spherical symmetry tell me.  I admit that I'm not expert in singularity resolution, though.  The central singularity being spacelike really seems to be the special case to me.